# Spring Security add/remove antMatchers and roles dynamically at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there a way to change this place dynamically? In other words, invoke the method that adds or removes antMatchers or override completely. map roles, etc.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //Change this configs dynamically at runtime
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Security version `5.6`, which is in `5.6.0.M3` as of now, you can create an `AuthorizationManager` bean and define place your rules anywhere you want, like so:

```java
@Autowired
private MyCustomAuthorizationManager access;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().access(access);
}
```

Or even better, you can define a `SecurityFilterChain` bean and make use of method parameter injection, instead of extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain app(HttpSecurity http, MyCustomAuthorizationManager access) throws Exception {
     ...
     http.authorizeRequests().access(access);
     ...
     return http.build();
}
```

There is a [great presentation](https://youtu.be/5tlU_Vjv8Ns?t=1992) showing how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up with this [solution](https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app). The solution is to close the current context and run the new one. Of course, it has the disadvantage because it causes downtime but I use a load balancer and several nodes so it's was ok for me.